# High performance many-to-many relationships in python

Tags: python

Given `cluster` and `node` objects:

```py
class Cluster():
   def __init__(self):
       pass


class Node():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

I am wondering what is the best data structure or design that meets the following requirements:

1. Find all the `clusters` that a given `node` belongs to.
2. Find all the `nodes` that belong to a given `cluster`.
3. Keep track a numerical quantity that represents how much each `node` belongs to a `cluster`, and each `cluster` to a `node`.
4. Ensure consistency when a `node` or `cluster` is deleted or added.
5. Fast lookups, additions and deletes. (in that order)
6. Low memory requirements.

The number of nodes and clusters will each be in the range of 100,000.

**More details of varying relevance:**

- A `node` will always belong to one or more clusters,
- A `cluster` will always contain one or more nodes.
- If a `cluster` has its only `node` removed the cluster should be deleted.
- A `node` will never have all of its clusters removed.
- Example: `node1` might belong 90% to `cluster14` and 10% to `cluster88`

I was thinking about using SQLite, but the problem is that storing serialized objects in the database is too slow. I could store `object_ids` in the database and then look those up in a `dict` that maps `object_ids` to object instances, but then there are consistency issues between the `dict` and the database. Additionally fetching a list of instances from the `dict` is a bit cumbersome.

I could possibly store the memory locations of the instances in SQLite but that seems dangerous, and we still have consistancy issues.

Comment: Sorry for delete/create (comment time edit rule). The requirements 1, 2, 3, and 4 combined read a few times span an interesting topic for me. Your clusters are like an overlapping grouping system where a node may belong to different clusters, or are the terms misleading (me with my background). Req 4 means what in case C1 is deleted and N1 belonged before to C1 and C2, will then N1 belong fully to C2 and what is with a node N3 that only belonged to C1 - will it raise an exception, be left dangling or reassociated with say C42? Please indicate more detail to the consistency requirement. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for update, so all cases in above comment questions have been addressed.

Comment: A fact that is relevant to potential answers, how many "edges" in this graph.  if there are exactly 100,000 of each of `node` s and `cluster`s, then the number of edges should be somewhere between 100,000 (if each node belongs to the minimum number of 1 clusters), and 10,000,000,000 (if every node belongs to every cluster).  Which is closer to the expected value?

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination. It's hard to know but to give you some rough numbers. If there are 100,000 nodes there will be about 1,000 clusters, with 90% of nodes belonging to one cluster only, and 10% belonging to an average of 30 clusters.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a similar data structure on a home project ; my own requirements called for a look alike architecture, except i called cluster "tags" (but the core concept is the same).

Here is how you may implement it:

- A list of clusters' names (or classes)
- A dictionnary of lists. In this dictionnary, keys are bitmasks marking the fact you belonging to a given set of clusters, and values are all the corresponding nodes. Say, if you have cluster 1 to 4, and `Node42` belonds to cluster 1 and 3, the dictionnary will have an entry looking like `5:[Node42, ...]`
- A dictionnary of singletons (it's an optional memory optimisation, since a set weight around 130 bytes in python if i remember correctly, having a dict that adress directly singletons help reduce memory consumption)

About requirements :

1. Depends, it is O(n) in my initial architecture, but with additional memory consumption you can have this instantly : add a field to each node with it's corresponding key in the dictionnary, then you just have to do the clusters lookups with the mask
2. O(n) : you have to read the data structure and aggregate nodes belonging to a given cluster. Best cases are fast, but heavily fragmented structure will be slow. For the same price, you can implement lookup of union and intersection of clusters, though
3. For clusters : iterate through dicts and sum lens. For nodes : iterate through mask and sum 1s.
4. This is the hardest part and require some programming, we are beyond the scope of stackoverflow probably as we speak about a hundred lines of Python or so.
5. If you want to fasten the lookups, you need to accept redundancy. If O(n) node lookup isn't acceptable, you can architecture differently, starting with a node list in each cluster. However, if your overlapping is big, so will be memory requirements.
6. We're in Python, memory requirement are heavy. However, you can externalize big dictionnaries or list to a Redis server. This would be my option to keep a fast lookup since we speak about an efficient in-memory storage.

If you are interested in the code I can release it for you to have a look, but I think you first need to make a choice or two regarding architecture : you can't have full Python full constant time memory efficient large scale data structure IMHO.